# How to assign date,which is navigated from previous page or form to date picker in Windows Phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I want to assign a date,which date is navigated from another page/form to date picker in my current page. When I looked at internet I got the answer like.

datepicker1.value = DateTime.Today;

But I am not getting datepicker.**value**

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and developing apps for Windows Phone 8.1.

I am retrieving date from database in one form*(consider as first page) and sending to  another form(secondary page). In secondary page I need to display date in secondary page, which is coming from first page.

Comment: So you want to access a DatePicker element on a page from a different page?

Comment: No, I can access a DatePicker element on a page from a different page, but my question was how to assign that DatePicker element to the current date picker which is present in current page..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this in your SecondPage

`var date= FirstPage.datepicker1.value`

I am assuming that FirstPage is the namespace of the Page from where you want assign the value. 
`namespace SomeThing
{
    class Program
    {
        public partial class SecondPage: PhoneApplicationPage
        {
            var date= FirstPage.datepicker1.value
        }
    }
}`

**EDIT**
Ok I got your point.
You can set the datePicker value in **OnNavigatedTo ** function.
And in the backend

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

{

```
    datePicker1.Date = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    datePicker1.MinYear = DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

}

You have to pass the Date as a parameter to the second page.
Consider date is the parameter, Now in First page you can write

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Text"] = date;
    }
```

And in your Second Page you have to receive the date and assign it to datePicker1.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    datePicker1.Date=(DateTime)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Text"]
}
```

Comment: OK. Thank you for your reply.. But my question was that, how to assign it to datepicker. Is it possible??

Comment: You are assigning current date, but how to assign datepicker value which accessed from the different page ?

Comment: Do you have two DatePickers(one in each page) and you want to assign the value of one DatePicker to another?

Comment: No, let me explain.. I am retrieving date from database in one form*(consider as first page) and sending to  another form(secondary page). In secondary page I need to display date in secondary page, which is coming from first page. Got my point?

Comment: Enhance your original posting!